# create a dummy column and populate with select

Tags: sql-server

I need to use a select query to create a dummy column and pad it with a constant value.  I found a partial answer to my question in a related post, here was the answer:

```
select name, address, 'No' as vacationing, Zipcode from mytable;
```

My question is what do you do if you want to pad it with a number, such as:

'9999' AS vacationing - I get an error with that

Also, what if I want the cell to be empty, such as;

'' AS vacationing - I get an error here also

TIA

Comment: What is the actual error msg?

Comment: Please show your actual query...

Comment: SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT 'I' AS Type, 'x9999x' AS [Customer Number], dbo.SITE.SITE_ID AS [Legacy ID], 'xEMPTYx' AS [Site Name], 
                      dbo.STORAGE.STORAGE_ID AS [Tank Number/id], 'xEmptyx' AS [Customer Data Source], 'xEmptyX' AS [Manifolded To], 
                      MAX(DISTINCT dbo.LOG_INVENTORY.LAST_UPDATED) AS [Reading DateTime], ROUND(dbo.STORAGE.GROSS_VOLUME, 0) AS Volume, 
                      'N' AS [End Of Day Inventory]

Comment: 'xEMPTYx' should be blank

Comment: 'x9999x' should be 9999

Comment: nvm, it just started working after I saved the query

Comment: Please use the edit button to add code to your question, rather than pasting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`'9999' AS vacationing` is perfectly valid.

you must be using `union` with different column type   -  hence error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, address, '9999' AS vacationing, Zipcode FROM mytable;
```

And:

```
SELECT name, address, '' AS vacationing, Zipcode FROM mytable;
```

Are both valid T-SQL queries. You don't say what error you're getting, but neither of these should throw an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have re-formatted your code to make it clearer in your answer.